# Can't remove placeholder Uppercase

Tags: html, css

I'm having a problem with the placeholder, not matter what I do, it's always uppercase. I've tried to add all the css style I can find that should help, but no luck so far. Can someone tell me why this happens`?

**My css for my searchbar**

```
#navigation-bar {
    height: 100%;
    width: 500px;
    float: right;
}

#search {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 60px;
    height: 100%;
}

#label {
    width: 60px;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 20;
}

#label label {
    display: block;
    width: 60px;
    height: 100%;
    background: url("../../images/search.png") no-repeat center center;
    font-size: 0;
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    text-indent: -9999px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

#label label:hover {
    background: url("../../images/search.png") no-repeat center center;
}

#label.active label {
    background: url("../../images/search.png") no-repeat center center;
}

#input {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 60px;
    width: 450px;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 5;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#input input {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: -450px;
    width: 450px;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 10px;
    border: none;
    background-color: #333;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 18px;
    backface-visibility: none;
    border-radius: 0;
    transition: left 0;
}


#input input:focus {
    outline: none;
}

#input.focus {
    z-index: 20;
}

#input.focus input {
    right: 0;
    transition: right 0.3s;
}


::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    text-transform: none;
}
:-moz-placeholder {
    text-transform: none;
}
::-moz-placeholder {
    text-transform: none;
}
:-ms-input-placeholder {  
    text-transform: none;
}
```

**Html**

```
<div class="content-container">
    <div class="top-wrapper">
        <div class="top">
            <div class="navigation">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                        <div id="navigation-bar" class="clearfix">
                            <form id="search" onkeypress="return event.keyCode != 13;" action="@Model.SearchPageUrl" method="post">
                                <div id="input"><input type="text" name="search-terms" id="search-terms" placeholder="@Model.SearchPlaceholder"></div>
                                <div id="label"><label for="search-terms" id="search-label">search</label></div>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Image of the problem**
[image]

Comment: Are you certain you're inspecting the same element that you have highlighted in the inspector? Its hard to debug without seeing your html.

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/style-placeholder-text/ Use this with `!important` and `text-transform:initial`

Comment: @ntgCleaner how does that help me, if you scroll Down in my css I have already defined those tags

Comment: @PeterHansen, can you use none? and I think you need `initial`

Comment: Can you post a link to a development location of your website or post more HTML. Hard to see what is causing this.

Comment: I would suggest to try to replicate the error on jsfiddle or similar to try to eliminate any other possible problem, e.g. a JS script that capitalises all words on the header. As @Djave said, it's hard to help you by just looking at screenshots.

Comment: @PeterHansen, Are you using something like bootstrap or wordpress?  It could be overriding your styles, since you don't have important on them

Comment: @PeterHansen Use mozilla debugger and see which events are linked to that element might be a good idea

Comment: Maybe the selectors for your placeholder formatting rules are not specific enough, please try putting `#input input` in front of them.

Comment: input { 
  text-transform: lowercase;
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont think you can just do `::-webkit-input-placeholder`

try with specificying the input first like so:

```
input::-webkit-input-placeholder {
   text-transform: lowercase;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not only would I do what @Brad is saying, but I would also add `!important` to your style.  This will hopefully ensure that no other style is taking over your input element.  Unfortunately, you can't "inspect" placeholder properties (at least I haven't been able to)

```
input::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    text-transform: none !important;
}
input:-moz-placeholder {
    text-transform: none !important;
}
input::-moz-placeholder {
    text-transform: none !important;
}
input:-ms-input-placeholder {  
    text-transform: none !important;
}
```

I may also suggest using `inherit` instead:

```
input::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    text-transform: inherit !important;
}
input:-moz-placeholder {
    text-transform: inherit !important;
}
input::-moz-placeholder {
    text-transform: inherit !important;
}
input:-ms-input-placeholder {  
    text-transform: inherit !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    text-transform: none;
}
:-moz-placeholder {
    text-transform: none;
}
::-moz-placeholder {
    text-transform: none;
}
:-ms-input-placeholder {  
    text-transform: none;
}
```

This code you have written, does what you want, it should work. I think you should check if it's not overwritten, by some other more precide CSS selector. Try adding more precise selector to check it, for example:

```
body input#search-terms::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    text-transform: none;
}
body input#search-terms:-moz-placeholder {
    text-transform: none;
}
body input#search-terms::-moz-placeholder {
    text-transform: none;
}
body input#search-terms:-ms-input-placeholder {  
    text-transform: none;
}
```